# The animation starts and stops by pressing and lifting the button, But animation stops at any frame in between

Tags: java, android, eclipse, animation

The animation starts and stops by pressing and lifting the button, But animation stops at any frame in between. I want the animation to precisely stop at the first image and start from the first image.

Below is my code:

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ImageView rocketImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ball_animation);
            rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();

             mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound);

        }

        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (rocketAnimation.isRunning()){
                    rocketAnimation.stop();
                }
                rocketAnimation.start();
                return false;
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(rocketAnimation.isRunning()){
                  rocketAnimation.stop();

                }
              }
            return super.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

    }


<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:duration="40" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image2" android:duration="40" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image3" android:duration="40" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/image4" android:duration="40" />

</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`, Replace `rocketAnimation.stop()` with `rocketAnimation.setOneShot(true)`